# Error Opening QGIS from Python (OS X)

Tags: pyqgis, installation, osx

I want to be able to access QGIS (2.14) from Python, but I am having all sorts of problems. Python keeps crashing when I try to import the library.

```
X-MacBook-Pro:~ X$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:17:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os 
>>> import sys
>>>sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python/')
>>> import qgis.core
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The crash log is below (it mentions the sip.so plugin, not sure if that is important)...

```
Process:               Python [8420]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.10 (2.7.10)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [8260]
Responsible:           Python [8420]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so
PlugIn Identifier:       sip.so
PlugIn Version:          ??? (0)

Date/Time:             2017-09-06 16:15:54.935 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F2073)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        21BC0F96-B3DF-96B4-A728-6F1EF2631B36


Time Awake Since Boot: 4700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000100018490
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x100018490:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000102d9a000-0000000102d9c000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9da56b52 strlen + 18
1   org.python.python               0x0000000102de5f96 PyString_FromFormatV + 489
2   org.python.python               0x0000000102e36717 PyErr_Format + 157
3   sip.so                          0x00000001030b1502 sip_api_export_module + 833
4   _core.so                        0x0000000103194aa7 init_core + 202
5   org.python.python               0x0000000102e40130 _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 140
6   org.python.python               0x0000000102e3ee2c 0x102da5000 + 630316
7   org.python.python               0x0000000102e3ea00 0x102da5000 + 629248
8   org.python.python               0x0000000102e3dc10 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1185
9   org.python.python               0x0000000102e23006 0x102da5000 + 516102
10  org.python.python               0x0000000102daf6fb PyObject_Call + 99
11  org.python.python               0x0000000102e2ddbb PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165
12  org.python.python               0x0000000102e29c0f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8283
13  org.python.python               0x0000000102e279be PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
14  org.python.python               0x0000000102e27367 PyEval_EvalCode + 48
15  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3c6bd PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 241
16  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3f3c7 0x102da5000 + 631751
17  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3f64f 0x102da5000 + 632399
18  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3ee2c 0x102da5000 + 630316
19  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3ea00 0x102da5000 + 629248
20  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3dc10 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1185
21  org.python.python               0x0000000102e23006 0x102da5000 + 516102
22  org.python.python               0x0000000102daf6fb PyObject_Call + 99
23  org.python.python               0x0000000102e2ddbb PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165
24  org.python.python               0x0000000102e29c0f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8283
25  org.python.python               0x0000000102e279be PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
26  org.python.python               0x0000000102e27367 PyEval_EvalCode + 48
27  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3c6bd PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 241
28  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3f3c7 0x102da5000 + 631751
29  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3f64f 0x102da5000 + 632399
30  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3ee2c 0x102da5000 + 630316
31  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3ea00 0x102da5000 + 629248
32  org.python.python               0x0000000102e3dbd8 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1129
33  org.python.python               0x0000000102e23006 0x102da5000 + 516102
34  org.python.python               0x0000000102daf6fb PyObject_Call + 99
35  org.python.python               0x0000000102e2ddbb PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165
36  org.python.python               0x0000000102e29c0f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8283
37  org.python.python               0x0000000102e279be PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
38  org.python.python               0x0000000102e27367 PyEval_EvalCode + 48
39  org.python.python               0x0000000102e475dd 0x102da5000 + 665053
40  org.python.python               0x0000000102e4740b PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 377
41  org.python.python               0x0000000102e46eff PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 192
42  org.python.python               0x0000000102e46da9 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 60
43  org.python.python               0x0000000102e58b6a Py_Main + 3094
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9da20235 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff5ce647f8  rbx: 0x00007fff5ce648d0  rcx: 0x0000000100018494  rdx: 0x0000000100018494
  rdi: 0x0000000100018490  rsi: 0x0000000102de668c  rbp: 0x00007fff5ce64740  rsp: 0x00007fff5ce64740
   r8: 0x00007fffa691d6b8   r9: 0x0000000100018494  r10: 0x0000000000000003  r11: 0xffffffffff9251d9
  r12: 0x00007fff5ce648d0  r13: 0x0000000000000030  r14: 0x00000001030be823  r15: 0x00000001030be824
  rip: 0x00007fff9da56b52  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000100018490

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

...so on, and so forth